# Importing allauth views causes Runtime error: django.contrib.sites.models.Site doesn't declare an explicit app_label

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-allauth

I have tried all the SO questions I could find, but I still cannot resolve my issue. I am switching my Django project to DRF, and first thing I did was to bring in django-allauth.

Here's the necessary bit of my `settings.py`

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'corsheaders',
    'rest_framework',
    'taggit',
    'taggit_serializer',
     
    # my apps
    'users', # CustomUser model
     ...

    # DRF stuff
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'rest_auth',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'rest_auth.registration',

    # debug in dev
    'django_extensions',
    'shell_plus',
    'livereload',
    'debug_toolbar',
]

SITE_ID = 1
```

Anytime I apply `mange.py makemigrations`, I get the following error:

> RuntimeError: Model class django.contrib.sites.models.Site doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an a
> pplication in INSTALLED_APPS.

After inspecting, I found that anytime I would use any of the [`allauth.account.views`](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/views.html) imports in my urls.py, I get this error. It doesn't even matter if I use the import or not, just importing alone is enough to trigger the error. How can I proceed?

I am using Django 3.1.7, and django allauth 0.44.0.

Comment: Are you using the latest Django version? I know they've enforced strict app labeling/naming in the latest release. Maybe the `allauth` is not up to date with those standards?